# Multiple stores with subfolders - nginx

Tags: multistore, store-view, nginx, multidomain

I want to configure a multistore shop like this:

**domain1**

- http://www.domain1.com/nl/ -> website 1, store view 1
- http://www.domain1.com/en/ -> website 1, store view 2
- http://www.domain1.com/de/ -> website 1, store view 3
- http://www.domain1.com/fr/ -> website 1, store view 4

**domain2**

- http://www.domain2.com/nl/ -> website 2, store view 1
- http://www.domain2.com/en/ -> website 2, store view 2
- http://www.domain2.com/de/ -> website 2, store view 3
- http://www.domain2.com/fr/ -> website 2, store view 4

*The store code approach is not possible because we need to have the same store code multiple times.*

What would be the best way to achieve this with nginx?

**My configuration**:
Ubuntu 16.04LTS, PHP7.1(FPM), nginx/1.10.3, Magento 2.2.2 CE

Comment: So you want to setup these things on your localhost right ?

Comment: store/website code is exactly what you need, this is the most safest and easiest solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done a setup with Magento 2.2 and nginx before, but with subdomains instead of folders.

So the setup was:

- nl.domain1.com, en.domain1.com,...
- nl.domain2.com, en.domain2.com,...

etc.

This is a modified version of the setup, maybe it helps you getting started.
Another/additional idea: Create 2 nginx config files (one for each domain) and use `alias` for the subfolders?

```
#default mapping
map $http_host $magesite {
        127.0.0.1 "website1_storeview1";
}

map $http_host $MAGE_SUBLOCATION {
    www.domain1.com /nl;
    www.domain1.com /en;
    www.domain1.com /de;
    www.domain1.com /fr;
    www.domain2.com /nl;
    www.domain2.com /en;
    www.domain2.com /de;
    www.domain2.com /fr;
}

map $http_host $MAGE_RUN_CODE {
    www.domain1.com website1_storeview1;
    www.domain1.com website1_storeview2;
    www.domain1.com website1_storeview3;
    www.domain1.com website1_storeview4;
    www.domain2.com website2_storeview1;
    www.domain2.com website2_storeview2;
    www.domain2.com website2_storeview3;
    www.domain2.com website2_storeview4;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass fpm:9000;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    include fastcgi_params;
    #fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE website;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE $MAGE_RUN_CODE;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
}
```

I am not an nginx expert but got my setup running in the end :)

Comment: Hi @Anna , where we using `MAGE_SUBLOCATION ` on this config  file?

Answer (score 1):

**Using subdirectorries**

Add the Language directory as subdirectories symlinking the `index.php` to the original one.
Then detect subdirectory + domain name in the `index.php` to set the active storecode.

Comment: He asked about nginx ;)

Comment: @AnnaVölkl oooops corrected that